# Embed PDF into wordpress

Tags: plugins, posts, embed, views, pdf

Is there a way to show a PDF file inside Post in Wordpress?
I used the  tag but if someone has Internet Download Manager the Dialog will appear to Download the PDF file and then if they click cancel they will not be able to see it, they can ONLY download it

Is there's a way to stop automatic download?

There are many plugins for that but the image quality is too bad.

Comment: Since you had tried existing solutions and quality is not sufficient, what other answer are you looking for? You will never have same degree of control over PDF as over HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable cross browser solution is to embed the .pdf in a `iframe`.

```
add_filter('media_send_to_editor', 'my_pdf_embed', 20, 3);

function my_pdf_embed($html, $id) {
    $attachment = get_post($id); //fetching attachment by $id passed through

    $mime_type = $attachment->post_mime_type; //getting the mime-type
    if ($mime_type == 'application/pdf') { //checking mime-type
        $src = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );

        //change the size to your liking
        $html = '<iframe width="500" height="500" src="'.$src.'"></iframe>';
        return $html; // return new $html    
    }
        return $html;
}
```

Comment: How can I apply this to a custom post ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Embed PDF Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dirtysuds-embed-pdf/) allows you to embed a pdf inside a viewer on your post or page.

Comment: This plugin hasn't been updated in over 2 years :/ and it is not work